# SQL query for Pershing sub string from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

1>

```
a:2{s:8:"folderid";s:28:"0B2cFhOMCK2KEOVBzbnZOczZsNkU";s:10:
"foldertext";s:17:"Home Health Files";}
```

2>

```
a:2{s:8:"folderid";s:28:"0B2cFhOMCK2KEOVBzbnZOczZsNkU";s:10:
"foldertext";s:12:"Agency Files";}
```

3>

```
  a:2{s:8:"folderid";s:28:"0B2cFhOMCK2KEMVB4SGFtVmozamc";s:10:"foldertext";s:9:"Dover HHC";}
```

I need folder name i.e `Home Health Files` and `Agency Files`,`Dover HHC` from the above strings.

i.e the last sub-string which is enclosed with ""

Comment: Just use charindex to find the correct position?

Comment: I sure hope you don't have this kind of gibberish in your actual tables. To parse this out you will need to do some string manipulation. So us what you have tried.

Comment: left(replace(SUBSTRING(role, CHARINDEX(''"'', role), CHARINDEX(''"'',role) - CHARINDEX(''"'', role) + Len(role)),''"'',''''),charindex('';'',replace(SUBSTRING(role, CHARINDEX(''"'', role), CHARINDEX(''"'',role) - CHARINDEX(''"'', role) + Len(role)),''"'',''''))-1 but i am able to get the 1st substring which is enclosed with "" i.e folderid but how to get the last one!!!!

Comment: Take a look at REVERSE.

Comment: Those strings look like the output from PHP's [serialize](http://php.net/serialize). It might be safer to use unserialize on the string and then the value is in `$array['foldertext']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @role VARCHAR(4000) = 'a:2{s:8:"folderid";s:28:"0B2cFhOMCK2KEOVBzbnZOczZsNkU";s:10:"foldertext";s:17:"Home Health Files";}'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@role,LEN(@role)-CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@role),CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@role),0)+1)+2,(LEN(@role)-CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@role),0)-1)-(LEN(@role)-CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@role),CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@role),0)+1)))
```